# Limit duration (length / time) of Uploaded Video

Tags: 7, files

I have a website that uses the [Video module](http://drupal.org/project/video) to allow users to upload videos. I want to limit the duration(both minimum and maximum) of the video that the user uploads.

**For Example:**

Users cannot upload videos that are more than 10mins and less than 5mins. So the duration of their videos should be in-between 5 to 10mins.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that at the moment, but you can set up your presets to limit the length of the transcoded video. I hope that is sufficient for you.

Comment: Thanks... Is there any other way to limit the length of the uploaded video (using custom code)?

Comment: If you are using FFmpeg, you could develop a validator that invokes FFmpeg and reads the length.